# How to calculate total amount of table records using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to calculate the total to pay of all the records found in the table, using jquery
[Here I show you the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXrQy.jpg)
***HTML***

```
<div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4>Customer information:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="customer_name">Customer:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="producto_name">Producto:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="producto_name" id="producto_name" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="product_price">Price</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_price" id="product_price" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="product_stock">Stock</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_stock" id="product_stock" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="product_quantity">quantity</label>
                                <input type="number" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity" value="1" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <input type="button" id="btnAddToList" value="Add to List" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5>Products:</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table id="dtProduct" class="table display border border-1" style="width: 100%;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Code</th>
                                    <th>Customer</th>
                                    <th>Product</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Stock</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="button" id="btnAddToList" value="Generate sale" class="btn btn-success">
                            <label for="" class="ml-auto mx-2 mt-1">Total:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="total_pay" id="total_pay" class="col-md-1 form-control" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***JavaScript***
This function allows me to add the form data to the table

```
function Add() {
    var item = 0;
    $('#btnAddToList').click(function () {
        item++;
        var customer_name = $('#customer_name').val();
        var producto_name = $('#producto_name').val();
        var product_price = $('#product_price').val();
        var product_stock = $('#product_stock').val();
        var product_quantity = $('#product_quantity').val();
        var Subtotal = product_price * product_quantity;

        var fila = '<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td>' + customer_name + '</td><td>' + producto_name + '</td><td>' + product_price + '</td><td>' + product_stock + '</td><td>' + product_quantity + '</td><td>' + Subtotal + '</td></tr>';
        var btn = document.createElement('tr');
        btn.innerHTML = fila;
        document.getElementById('dtProduct').appendChild(btn);

        //* ==========================================================
        // here get total to pay

       //
    });
}
```

pressing the button adds the data to the table but I can't get the total to pay.
 Can anybody help me? thank you very much

Comment: Storing data in html is a big mistake.

Comment: I'm a beginner, I don't have much knowledge about this.
Why is it a mistake and how could I do it?

Comment: Store in javascript vars. Global, if you want. Create array and push objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. it is bad habbit to create event inside other js function.
2. you need to add class for your subtotal `td`.

try below solution

```js
var item = 0;
    $('#btnAddToList').click(function () {
        item++;
        var customer_name = $('#customer_name').val();
        var producto_name = $('#producto_name').val();
        var product_price = $('#product_price').val();
        var product_stock = $('#product_stock').val();
        var product_quantity = $('#product_quantity').val();
        var Subtotal = product_price * product_quantity;

        var fila = '<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td>' + customer_name + '</td><td>' + producto_name + '</td><td>' + product_price + '</td><td>' + product_stock + '</td><td>' + product_quantity + '</td><td class="subtotal">' + Subtotal + '</td></tr>';
        var btn = document.createElement('tr');
        btn.innerHTML = fila;
        document.getElementById('dtProduct').appendChild(btn);

        //* ==========================================================
        // here get total to pay

       //
       var total =0;
       $('.subtotal').each(function(index, tr) { 
        debugger
         total =total+  parseInt($(this).text());
});
$('#total_pay').val(total);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4>Customer information:</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="customer_name">Customer:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="producto_name">Producto:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="producto_name" id="producto_name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="product_price">Price</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="product_price" id="product_price" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="product_stock">Stock</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="product_stock" id="product_stock" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="product_quantity">quantity</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity" value="1" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <input type="button" id="btnAddToList" value="Add to List" class="btn btn-primary" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h5>Products:</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table id="dtProduct" class="table display border border-1" style="width: 100%;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Code</th>
                                        <th>Customer</th>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Stock</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Subtotal</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="button" id="btnAddToList" value="Generate sale" class="btn btn-success" >
                                <label for="" class="ml-auto mx-2 mt-1">Total:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="total_pay" id="total_pay" class="col-md-1 form-control" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way quick way without modifying too much code. Add a class to your subtotal td, I added `class="td-subtotal"`.

```
  <table id="dtProduct" class="table display border border-1" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="td-subtotal"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Then loop through the in jquery after your button click. The loop will add to the total variable, then assign it to the total input field.

The code below contains the additional td-subtotal class during appending to the table.

```
$('#btnAddToList').click(function () {
        item++;
        var customer_name = $('#customer_name').val();
        var producto_name = $('#producto_name').val();
        var product_price = $('#product_price').val();
        var product_stock = $('#product_stock').val();
        var product_quantity = $('#product_quantity').val();
        var Subtotal = product_price * product_quantity;

        var fila = '<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td>' + customer_name + '</td><td>' + producto_name + '</td><td>' + product_price + '</td><td>' + product_stock + '</td><td>' + product_quantity + '</td><td class="td-Subtotal">' + Subtotal + '</td></tr>';
        var btn = document.createElement('tr');
        btn.innerHTML = fila;
        document.getElementById('dtProduct').appendChild(btn);

        // initialize
        var total = 0;

        // loop
        $(".td-subtotal").each(function(){

          // get value
          total+=$(this).html();
        });

        // assign
        $("#total_pay").val(total);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to be clear and understandable if not sorry i will edit

```js
const TD = $("<td></td>");
const TR = $("<tr></tr>");
const PRODUCTTABLE = $("#dtProduct");
const PRODUCTTOTAL = $("#AllPrice");

function Add() {
  var item = 0;
  $('#btnAddToList').click(function() {
    item++;
    var customer_name = $('#customer_name').val();
    var producto_name = $('#producto_name').val();
    var product_price = $('#product_price').val();
    var product_stock = $('#product_stock').val();
    var product_quantity = $('#product_quantity').val();
    var Subtotal = parseInt(product_price) * parseInt(product_quantity);



    let cCode = TD.clone().html(item);
    let cName = TD.clone().html(customer_name);
    let pName = TD.clone().html(producto_name);
    let pPrice = TD.clone().html(product_price);
    let pStock = TD.clone().html(product_stock);
    let pQuantity = TD.clone().html(product_quantity);
    let pTotalPrice = TD.clone().html(Subtotal).addClass("rowPrice");


    let newRow = TR.clone().append(
      item,
      cName,
      pName,
      pPrice,
      pStock,
      pQuantity,
      pTotalPrice,
    );


    //        loop through your rows to get your sum of prices
    let price = Subtotal; // get newly added sub total to tmp variable
    PRODUCTTABLE.find("tbody").children("tr").each(function() {
      let otherPrices = $(this).children(".rowPrice").text();
      price += parseInt((otherPrices.length > 0) ? price : 0); // using ternary if to prevent empty row
    });
    Subtotal = price; // at last give your price to subtotal


    PRODUCTTABLE.find("tbody").append(newRow); // add new row after calcule old prices

    PRODUCTTOTAL.find("#total_pay").val(Subtotal);
  });
}


Add();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4>Customer information:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="customer_name">Customer:</label>
              <input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="producto_name">Producto:</label>
              <input type="text" name="producto_name" id="producto_name" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="product_price">Price</label>
              <input type="text" name="product_price" id="product_price" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="product_stock">Stock</label>
              <input type="text" name="product_stock" id="product_stock" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="product_quantity">quantity</label>
              <input type="number" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity" value="1" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <input type="button" id="btnAddToList" value="Add to List" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5>Products:</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <table id="dtProduct" class="table display border border-1" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer" id="AllPrice">
          <div class="row">
            <input type="button" value="Generate sale" class="btn btn-success">
            <label for="" class="ml-auto mx-2 ml-auto">Total:</label>
            <input type="text" name="total_pay" disabled id="total_pay" class="col-md-1 form-control" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```